Place a character at a certain place in a string, only if the string is a certain number of characters
I have strings that are structured like this:
vector <- c("CBR0", "CBR1", "CBR2", "CBR3", "CBR4", "CBR5", "CBR10", "CBR11")


I would like to insert a zero after 'CBR' for only the CBR numbers 0-9.  CBR numbers >= 10 don't need to be changed. The resulting vector would look like this:
vector <- c("CBR00", "CBR01", "CBR02", "CBR03", "CBR04", "CBR05", "CBR10", "CBR11")


Is there a way I can do this using stringr?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Using str_replace
library(stringr)

str_replace(vector, "CBR(\\d)$", "CBR0\\1")
[1] "CBR00" "CBR01" "CBR02" "CBR03" "CBR04" "CBR05" "CBR10" "CBR11"

A more generalized approach can be
str_replace(vector, "(\\D+)(\\d)$", "\\10\\2")
[1] "CBR00" "CBR01" "CBR02" "CBR03" "CBR04" "CBR05" "CBR10" "CBR11"


You can use sub("(\\D+)(\\d)$", "\\10\\2", vector) directly and avoid using stringr package.

@JilberUrbina Very true, I just wanted to stay in the "tidyverse" because it's directly addressed in the question.

Thanks so much for the help.  I appreciate the more generalizable code also for future work.

We can use str_replace to match all the numbers, instead of giving a direct replacement we can give a function to generate the replacement based on the match. In this case, str_pad is used to pad the matched digits up to width 2 with 0s.
This is a nice general approach in that it doesn't matter if the letter part is always the same or not, if the numbers are always at the end, you could just as easily pad to to any width, pad with other characters, etc.
library(stringr)
str_replace(
  vector, 
  pattern = "[0-9]+",
  replacement = \(x) str_pad(x, width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0")
)
# [1] "CBR00" "CBR01" "CBR02" "CBR03" "CBR04" "CBR05" "CBR10" "CBR11"


Here, we want our regex to match CBR, a digit, and then NOT another digit after that.
Here we can use (CBR[0-9])(?!\\d)
and using str_replace, we have our final answer
library(stringr)

vector <- c("CBR0", "CBR1", "CBR2", "CBR3", "CBR4", "CBR5", "CBR10", "CBR11")

vector <- str_replace(vector, "(CBR[0-9])(?!\\d)", "\\10")

